# H2 Database, problems getting data from tables

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm creating a JavaFX application, I've connected to the database fine. However when i look to get data from the tables i get the error

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "LECTURE" not found; SQL
>   statement: SELECT NAME FROM Lecture [42102-192]

and I'm 100% sure i'm connected to the database and the table is definitely there, any suggestions on why this is?

hear is my connection code and the code i am running just so you can see

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    //static reference to itself
    private static ConnectionFactory instance = new ConnectionFactory();
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:file:~/db\\.";
    public static final String USER = "notepad";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "org.h2.Driver";

    //private constructor
    private ConnectionFactory() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Connection createConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.");
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return instance.createConnection();
    }
}
```

And the query being run

```
private void onLoadYearSelect() {

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT NAME FROM Lecture";
        ResultSet years = stat.executeQuery(query);
        while(years.next()){
            yearSelect.setValue(years.getString("NAME"));
            System.out.println(years.getString("NAME"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void initialize(){
    onLoadYearSelect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says the table doesn't exist, then it really doesn't exist.

Most likely, you are not actually connecting to the correct database.  In fact, by default, if the connection string points to a non-existent database, it just creates an empty database on the fly, which would explain your error.

It's probably too late now (because there is probably a 2nd database created already somewhere), but to avoid this confusion, it's not a bad idea to include `IFEXISTS=TRUE` in the connection string so that it fails if the database doesn't exist, rather than creating an empty one that will mask the true problem.

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:file:~/db\\.;IFEXISTS=TRUE";
```

However, one thing you can still try to debug the problem, is to add `IFEXISTS=TRUE` to the connection string. Then move or rename the database *you think* it should be connecting to so as to make the connection string invalid. Basically, force it to fail.  If the code still connects to the database successfully, then you'll know the connection string is not pointing to the location you think it is.

Comment: But it's connecting to the database using the password and username that i created, and the path to the database that i got from clicking on the Database and getting it from the properties, which under the drop down has the tables.

Comment: It's just started working today, must of been my IDE playing up.